# How would I implement an IInterface class with this code that calculates area of circle, rectangle, triangle?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, areas

I need to further my knowledge of `IInterface` classes used with abstract classes. Whether this stuff is ever used have work requirements to learn a little more about it.

What I think an interface is (this works and calculates area for 3 items, `Rectangle`, `Triangle`, `Circle` using values provided):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(4, 8, "Rectangle");

    Triangle t = new Triangle(4, 4, "Triangle");

    Circle c = new Circle(3, "Circle");

    r.DisplayArea();
    Console.WriteLine();
    t.DisplayArea();
    Console.WriteLine();
    c.DisplayArea();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is my abstract class. It looks like it deals with the name of what is being measured:

```
namespace DrawShapes
{
    abstract class Shape
    {
        public string name;

        public abstract void DisplayArea();

        public Shape(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

I'm not positively sure but wouldn't these be in the `IInterface` class and get set or called somehow? Definitely not an expert at this object oriented stuff.

```
public int Radius { get; set; }
public int Height { get; set; }
public int Width { get; set; }
```

Instead, I am hardcoding the parameters into the "function call":

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(4, 8, "Rectangle");

    Triangle t = new Triangle(4, 4, "Triangle");

    Circle c = new Circle(3, "Circle");
}
```

I personally can't think of why or how I would use `IInterface`.

Just to be complete and maybe help someone who is looking for stuff like this, here are my classes to calculate areas.There are other SO answers to calculate areas, this question is about `IInterface` and abstract classes:

```
namespace DrawShapes
{
    class Rectangle : Shape
    {
        public int length;
        public int width;

        public Rectangle(int length, int width, string name) : base(name)
        {
            //this.angles = angles;
            this.length = length;
            this.width = width;
        }

        public override void DisplayArea()
        {
            Console.Write(name + "--");
            Console.Write(length * width);
        }
    }

    class Triangle : Shape
    {
        // public int angles;
        public int width;
        public int height;

        public Triangle(int width, int height, string name) : base(name)
        {
            //this.angles = angles;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public override void DisplayArea()
        {
            Console.Write(name + "--");
            Console.Write((width * height) / 2);
        }
    }

    class Circle : Shape
    {
        public int radius;

        public Circle(int radius, string name) : base(name)
        {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public override void DisplayArea()
        {
            Console.Write(name + "--");
            Console.Write(3.22 * radius * radius);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Ha. Yes, wouldn't the question be what the title is: How would I impliment an IInterface class with this code that calculates area of circle, rectangle, triangle? I'm being told with abstract classes that an "Interface" class can be used to reduce duplicate code. I really am not very smart at this computer science stuff. How would I reword it? I was assuming someone could say, "no, look just paste this part here, and then call it like this") Please forgive me. I've been working day and night for the last 2 days trying to meet some learning requirements at work.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking. An interface defines a contract (i.e. a set of signatures) that a class must implement. There is no actual code in an interface other than method, property, or other declarations with no bodies. An abstract class on the other hand can contain ordinary members, virtual member (members with default implementation that can be overridden), and abstract members (same as an interface - member declarations with no bodies). So you could actually use an abstract class to avoid duplicate code (via ordinary or virtual members), but not an interface.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I personally think what I built works just fine and 10,000 years from now when only roaches are using my code it will still work great. However, I have a boss and team lead at work that want me to occasionally answer questions for potential grade increases. So far I'm convinced it's too intellectual. Oh well. thanks for your attention.

Comment: I have to agree with @TimWilson, ```Interfaces``` give you a common contract.  So your interface could have a single method ```CalculateArea``` but you will still need code in each implementation, i.e. Rectangle, Square, Circle to calculate that area.  Even having an abstract class will be useless.  Maybe only useful to share measurements between Square and Rectangle.  At the end of the day, are you asking us to explain what ```interfaces``` and ```abstract classes``` are or are you asking whether the above code can be simplified?

Comment: Boy thanks for sticking with me on this one. I guess if simplifying my code using these types of classes would help. I do have some good info in your comments to study tomorrow when I cut my vacation short and have a whole day. Could actually drawing these shapes take advantage of an abstract class and interface class, given X,Y, width, height, radius values? Could they be stored in an interface? Or at least the "get/set" stuff for those variables? This OO stuff is like playing guitar for me: I can rip it up playing rock stuff (3 chords) but I can't play jazz or hear the chord changes.